#  GWT (or javascript) library for couchDB

Tags: javascript, gwt, couchdb, gwt-platform

I'm looking for a good design (best practices) to integrate a couchDB layer with my GWT app.

I did some research and found the [gwt-couchdb](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-gwt) project which seems to propose a method to integrate GWT and couchDB in a more clean way. But i'm not sure how this tool works and if its proposed solution is worth using it?

in fact we need a pure client side gwt library for gwt. a library that doesn't need a java backend server to run like [Ektorp](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp) . i found i found [BrowserChouch](http://hg.toolness.com/browser-couch/raw-file/blog-post/index.html) which seems to be a javascript lib for couchdb..yet i'm not clear if this is a reliable library and how to use it in gwt.

do you know of such libraries for chouchdb to be used with js or gwt on client side?

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with RDBMS'es, switching to a document databases can be jarring.  Before diving into CouchDB, make sure you read [CouchDB Definitive Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/) cover-to-cover.

Because CouchDB is accessed via simple HTTP requests, the database driver you choose is not very important. `gwt-couchdb` looks perfectly fine -- however, you could probably write your own driver in a few hours after reading the [Document API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API).

Your biggest design concerns will be:

1. Modeling your data as loosely coupled "documents" suitable for a document store
2. Outlining exactly how you will query those documents, so you can build your CouchDB views

Remember that your data model should dictate your choice of database, not the other way around.  Document stores like CouchDB and MongoDB are often a great choice, but if referential integrity is a hard requirement you may need to look elsewhere (e.g. PostgreSQL).

Comment: i've worked before a little bit with Mongo-db and have some concepts about document based stores like chouchDB but not a profound understanding of this tool. i was just wondering if there exists some established design pattern that was proven and tested to be used in GWT? or does using the couchdb backend in GWT apps is relative to the specific gwt app and there are no proven design patterns for the integration of these two tools?

Comment: I forgot to mention that we in the team did research and found that we need a document store db and that's why we selected couchDB.

Comment: Because CouchDB is just a simple REST HTTP endpoint, you don't need special design patterns for integrating with a web framework or anything else.  It's just HTTP!  Ease of integration is a big part of CouchDB's allure.  Best of luck..

Comment: in fact i need a pure javascript or gwt client side couchdb library that does'nt require a java backend server to run. i found http://hg.toolness.com/browser-couch/raw-file/blog-post/index.html ..do you know of such libraries for chouchdb to be used with js or gwt on client side?

Comment: @othman I would recommend the jquery.couch.js library.  It's well commented, and I believe CouchDB's own Futon web application uses it to communicate with the database.  You can find the source code here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/couchdb/trunk/share/www/script/jquery.couch.js?view=log  

You can look at other JavaScript library options here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Related_Projects

Comment: thank you for these suggestions i'll take a look at the jquery.couch.js library.